# How do I wire a ground rail to a VEROboard?

Tags: breadboard

I’m looking to move my project from a breadboard to a vero board. However, I’m not sure how to go about soldering in my ground and power connections as the veroboard doesn't seem to have dedicated ground and power rails like the breadboard.

I’ve also attached a photo of my schematic in its current state.

Also, I’m using an Arduino Nano Board as opposed to the UNO featured in the schematic. (I’ve just used it as a placeholder as I could find a component for the nano.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Project Schematic]

Here’s a photo of the type of veroboard I have:

[image: veroboard]

Comment: A minor correction in terminology: Your board - one with no interconnections - is usually known as perf-board. [Veroboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veroboard), aka strip board, has holes already connected in rows. Thus it's easy to assign power, ground, and signal rails, and with a layout that takes good advantage of the strips, it requires fewer hand-wired connections.

Comment: Ahh got it - thanks!

Comment: sometimes i solder a striped 20AWG solid wire along the edge for an ad-hoc easily solder-able ground rail.

Comment: Ahh good shout @dandavis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's nothing special about ground. It's just a wire like any other.

You *could* designate a row of holes as ground then link them all together, but you don't need to. Just wire your grounds together as you would any other connection.

Comment: Ahh fair enough! So does this also apply to power?

Comment: Yep. Everything is just wires.

Comment: Makes sense! Thanks for your help! 